# how to print file type in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

```css
#!/bin/bash


echo "" >> "regular file"
echo "" >> "Directory file"
echo "" >> "executable file"
target="/home/personal/scripts/07_22_13/ford/$1"
for f in "$target"/*
do
    echo $(basename $f) | ls -la
    if [[ -x "$f" ]];
    then
        echo "File '$f' is executable"
    elif [[ -r "$f" ]]; 
    then
        echo "file '$f' is regular"
    else echo "file '$f' is directory"
         echo "*(-^/)"
    fi
done
```

the code print all files with the access rights
how i can print beside every file which the type(regular,directory,executable)

---

Comment: why not just `stat` the file? -x/-f are just doing stat calls internally. calling stat directly will give you all of that info at once.

Comment: What is `echo $(basename $f) | ls -la` supposed to do? `ls` doesn't read from standard input, so why are you piping to it?

Comment: Maybe you meant `ls -la "$f"`?

Comment: Why don't you just use the `file` command? `file "$target"/*`

Comment: i removed this command, in addition the script must print all files in directory and beside every file must print the type(regular,directory, executable)

Answer (score 0):

```
if [[ -x "$file" ]]; # File is executable
if [[ -d "$file" ]]; # Is a directory
```

Comment: how i can to print the type beside every file ?

Comment: @sabaali : Actually, if i understand correctly, anything in linux system is considered a file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
 #!/bin/bash

 target="/path/to/target/"

 for file in `find ${target}`
 do
     stat --format=%n\ -\ %F\ -\ %A $file
     # %n prints the filename
     # %F prints the filetype
     # %A prints the permissions
     #For more info stat --help or man stat
 done
```